# Reg Expression matching abcd['xcvjygj']

Tags: regex

abcd['xcv'] ==> match

abcd[0] ==> unmatch

123[0] ==> unmatch

123['tyu'] ==> unmatch

kjh['utyryfty'] ==> match

*the format that should match*: **AlphaString['AlphaString']** (including single quotes and square brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it works for those 5 examples you posted

`[a-zA-Z]+\[\'[a-zA-Z]+\'\]`

Comment: Hi Pedral, thanks for the quick response, it really helped.